# flutter charts timeseries bar chart with x axis time as label

Tags: flutter, charts, dependencies

i'm using **charts_flutter: ^0.12.0** to implement bar chart with fixed time like 6,8,10,12,14,16,18,22 hours of the day in x axis, but with no success, tried the example but i get only two label's on the x axis 6 and 18 corresponding to the data, kindly help me with implementing the same. Trying to achieve as shown in the pic[image]

The code sample i have tried is

```
    class ChartsDaily extends StatelessWidget {
  List<charts.Series<dynamic, DateTime>> seriesList = _createSampleData();
  bool animate = false;

  //ChartsDaily(this.seriesList, {this.animate = false});
  ChartsDaily({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  /// Creates a [TimeSeriesChart] with sample data and no transition.
  factory ChartsDaily.withSampleData() {
    return ChartsDaily();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return charts.TimeSeriesChart(
      seriesList,
      defaultRenderer: charts.BarRendererConfig<DateTime>(
          barRendererDecorator:
              charts.BarLabelDecorator<DateTime>() // charts.BarLabelDecorator
          ),
      animate: animate,
      // Optionally pass in a [DateTimeFactory] used by the chart. The factory
      // should create the same type of [DateTime] as the data provided. If none
      // specified, the default creates local date time.
      // dateTimeFactory: const charts.LocalDateTimeFactory(),
      domainAxis: charts.DateTimeAxisSpec(
        tickProviderSpec: charts.DayTickProviderSpec(increments: [1]),
        tickFormatterSpec: charts.AutoDateTimeTickFormatterSpec(
            day: charts.TimeFormatterSpec(
                format: 'HH:mm', transitionFormat: 'HH:mm')),
      ),
      secondaryMeasureAxis: charts.NumericAxisSpec(
          renderSpec: charts.GridlineRendererSpec(
              lineStyle: charts.LineStyleSpec(
                  dashPattern: [4, 4],
                  color: charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(Colors.grey.shade300))),
          tickProviderSpec: charts.BasicNumericTickProviderSpec(
            desiredMinTickCount: 5,
            desiredTickCount: 5,
            dataIsInWholeNumbers: true,
            zeroBound: true,
          )),

      // domainAxis: charts.DateTimeAxisSpec(
      //   tickProviderSpec: charts.DateTimeEndPointsTickProviderSpec(),
      //   tickFormatterSpec: charts.AutoDateTimeTickFormatterSpec(
      //     day: charts.TimeFormatterSpec(
      //         format: 'HH:mm', transitionFormat: 'HH:mm', noonFormat: 'HH:mm'),
      //     // hour: charts.TimeFormatterSpec(format: 'Hm', transitionFormat: 'Hm'),
      //   ),
      //   showAxisLine: false,
      //   viewport: charts.DateTimeExtents(
      //       start: DateTime(2022, 05, 04, 06), end: DateTime(2022, 05, 04, 22)),
      // ),
    );
  }

  /// Create one series with sample hard coded data.
  static List<charts.Series<TimeSeriesSales, DateTime>> _createSampleData() {
    final data = [
      TimeSeriesSales(DateTime(2022, 5, 4, 6, 0), 5),
      TimeSeriesSales(DateTime(2022, 5, 4, 10, 30), 25),
      TimeSeriesSales(DateTime(2022, 5, 4, 14, 0), 100),
      TimeSeriesSales(DateTime(2022, 5, 4, 18, 0), 75),
    ];

    return [
      charts.Series<TimeSeriesSales, DateTime>(
        id: 'Sales',
        colorFn: (_, __) => charts.MaterialPalette.blue.shadeDefault,
        domainFn: (TimeSeriesSales sales, _) => sales.time,
        measureFn: (TimeSeriesSales sales, _) => sales.sales,
        data: data,
      )
    ];
  }
}

/// Sample time series data type.
class TimeSeriesSales {
  final DateTime time;
  final int sales;

  TimeSeriesSales(this.time, this.sales);
}
```

Also need to have y axis values not starting from 0. TIA

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the `StaticNumericTickProviderSpec` for the `domainAxis` of your chart.

[This is the example from Google](https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/axes/statically_provided_ticks.html). I hope it can help you